# Does an Activity-managed Cursor invoke requery() on another thread?

Tags: android

From within an `Activity` I query my database from an `AsyncTask`, and I pass the result `Cursor` to `startManagingCursor()`. From the docs, a managed cursor will automatically invoke `requery()` when an activity is restarted.

My question is, is requery() invoked from a background thread? If not and this runs on the UI thread and the query takes a long time to return this could cause a Application Not Responding dialog, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API docs were updated recently with a note about this method:

"it results in Cursor queries being performed on the application's UI thread and thus can cause poor responsiveness or even Application Not Responding errors"

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY

So it would appear that yes, requery() is not invoked from a background thread, and as the above comment says, it should not be used.